# Localization of an Artisan console command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, protected

I'm writing a [command line program](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan) for my Laravel app and would like it to be localizable. Since the help text for the command is defined as part of the `$signature` class variable, I tried to create it like this:

```
/**
 * The name and signature of the console command.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $signature = sprintf(
    "myapp:command {--i|id %s}",
    __("This is some help text for the ID")
);
```

However, I get this error message:

> PHP Fatal error:  Constant expression contains invalid operations

I assume that `protected` class variables are treated kind of like constants, so how can I provide a properly localizable string for the help text? Is there some way I can provide the text after the object is instantiated?

Comment: What about defining the signature in the constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions can't be used in property declarations but they can be used in constructors, this works fine:

```
/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->signature = sprintf(
        "myapp:command {--i|id %s}",
        __("This is some help text for the ID")
    );
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Comment: That was easy. Thanks!